# Hashing objects in Java?

Tags: java, hash

This is a homework question so I'm not looking for specific implementation but more an understanding of how to implement the following:

I have to create a hash table class, I understand how a hash table works but I am confused about how it actually hashes objects. In the examples we've seen we generally see integers get stored in a hash table (for simplicity) and they are hashed using an algorithm such as `value%10`.

I'm fine with this but confused about the following. We have been asked to write a class that can take any object and provide methods for insertion etc. I'm not sure how I can call `Object%10` considering I can't just find the modulus of an object. With this in mind given I'm not to know what sort of object a user could pass to this class (it could be one they have written themselves) how are you expected to write a hash function for all possible objects? Am I missing something here?

I've tried Googling but I'm not exactly sure what to Google so I'm coming up with not much, thanks

Comment: On the first glance, I read the question as *Hashing Objects Helps Java*. Please re-frame the question and avoid caps at the start of each word.

Comment: @R.J Title has been fixed sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashcode doesnt always have to be `value%10`, In case of object it is a number derived using state of object ie attributes of object.
If you class like

```
public class MyClass {
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

then Hashcode can be simple as

```
public int hashCode() {
    int result = a + b;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I assumed that the hashcode was generated by the hash table itself and not the object? Is it common practice for the object itself to provide the hashcode implementation?

Comment: @gRnt: Hashtable calls the `hashcode` method of object and uses it to decide the indertion location.

Comment: Ok just to clarify I thought the hashtable itself did the hard work of determining what the hashcode for the object was and not that the object actually implemented this itself (this is where I was getting confused) thanks.

Comment: @gRnt: Hashtable just calls the method and object itself decides the implementation

Comment: @gRnt `hashCode` has to be implemented by the object's class, otherwise the hashtable (for being generally applicable, and not only for one type of object) would have to know how to create the hash code for each possible, existing and future, class, which is rather impractical.

Comment: @Karna: a general-purpose hash table can't do that for the object, because it can't peek into them (unless it uses reflection, which would be a bad idea). What the "production quality" hash tables (`Hashtable`, `HashMap`) do is to post-process the hash code produced by the object to reduce the effect of a few common implementation problems of `hashCode`. They effectively hash the hash again.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Was not aware of it. Better I will keep my answer simple s OP ssems to be novice

Comment: @Karna: I agree that this doesn't belong in the answer ;-) also, that comment should have been directed at gRnt, sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

Check the methods of [the `Object` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). **Every** object in Java has those methods. See if one of them can help you.